# How to put image pixel data into an array in code?

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to integrate the icon pixel data into the code of my C++ program. I'm using the SFML library. The window method to set the icon looks like this:

```
void setIcon(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const Uint8 *pixels)
```

Of course, SFML provides methods to read image files and get to the pixels. However, I don't want to read an image file; instead I would like to have the image pixel data in code, to be compiled into the executable. Something like:

```
sf::Uint8 pixels[] = { <image pixel data> };
```

How can I do that (if at all possible)?

Comment: The syntax that you guessed is correct, other than marking the array as `const`.  Have you tried it?  Or are you asking how to determine the values for each of the pixels?

Comment: One way to do this is to make a program that reads an image and writes out a header file with the array of pixels. Then you just include that header.

Comment: @0x5453: Yes, the question is about how to get to the values.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: That's an interesting idea. I will try that.

Comment: `xxd` can convert an arbitrary file (text or binary) into C style array of bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Eljay's comment:

running `xxd -i icon.png` creates a file `icon.h` with the following content:

```
unsigned char icon_png[] = { <image file data> };
unsigned int icon_png_len = 264;
```

Note that `icon_png` does not contain the pixel data, but the whole file (thus, including the file header). With SFML, this is the code to get to the pixel data:

```
sf::Image icon;
icon.loadFromMemory(icon_png, icon_png_len);
window.setIcon(icon.getSize().x, icon.getSize().y, icon.getPixelsPtr());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can open the image in Gimp
export it(Ctrl+E) as `.c` or `.h` then include the file in project